# How to convert a dataframe to sparse matrix with mixed column types?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I have a data frame of following format:

```
df:

key   f1    f2
k1    10    a, b, c
k2    20    b, d
k3    15    NaN
```

The column f2 has a bag of words as values. I want to convert this data frame into a sparse matrix, as distinct words in f2 run to a few thousands. The end result I am expecting is of following format:

```
key    f1  f2.a  f2.b  f2.c  f2.d
k1     10   1     1     1     0
k2     20   0     1     0     1
k3     15   0     0     0     0
```

I could figure out how to independently create a sparse matrix just out of key and f2 field. I am first melting the column f2 so I get following dataframe:

```
df1:
key  f2
k1   a
k1   b
k1   c
k2   b
k2   d
```

Then I am encoding f2, and using the LabelEncoder from sklearn.preprocessing package to encode f2. Then I am creating a sparse matrix as follows:

```
df1['trainrow'] = np.arrange(df1.shape[0])
sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(df1.shape[0], (df1.trainrow, df1.f2_encoded)))
```

This creates a sparse matrix by doing a one-hot encoding of field f2. But I am not sure how I can concatenate this with the numerical field f1.

Comment: I would use `CountVectorizer` from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text` for this task - it should be much faster

Comment: @MaxU I am facing one problem with the CountVectorizer. My bag of words are separated by commas, and each word may have spaces. I don't want the vectorizer to treat them as different features. Can we somehow control this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df[['key','f1']], df.f2.str.get_dummies(sep=', ').add_prefix('f2.')], axis=1)
print (df)
  key  f1  f2.a  f2.b  f2.c  f2.d
0  k1  10     1     1     1     0
1  k2  20     0     1     0     1
2  k3  15     0     0     0     0
```

In very large distinct values `get_dummies` is very slow, you can use custom function `f`:

```
def f(category_list):
    n_categories = len(category_list)
    return pd.Series(dict(zip(category_list, [1]*n_categories)))

#remove NaN rows and create list of values by split
df1 = df.f2.dropna().str.split(', ').apply(f).add_prefix('f2.')
df2 = pd.concat([df[['key','f1']], df1], axis=1)
#replace NaN to 0 by position from 3.column to end of df
df2.iloc[:, 2: ] = df2.iloc[:, 2: ].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df2)
  key  f1  f2.a  f2.b  f2.c  f2.d
0  k1  10     1     1     1     0
1  k2  20     0     1     0     1
2  k3  15     0     0     0     0
```

**Timings**:

```
In [256]: %timeit s.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 16s per loop

In [257]: %timeit (s.dropna().str.split(', ').apply(f).fillna(0).astype(int))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.95 s per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10000, size=(1000,1000))).astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1)
print (s)


df2 = s.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
print (df2)

def f(category_list):
    n_categories = len(category_list)
    return pd.Series(dict(zip(category_list, [1]*n_categories)))

print (s.dropna().str.split(', ').apply(f).fillna(0).astype(int))
```

Comment: This solution works great with a limited no:of distinct values in field f2. But I have ~20k distinct values in the field, and it is taking forever due to this. Any suggestion how I can handle such a large data set? (I was trying to use the sparse matrix for the same reason)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the optimal way I wanted to solve this, so posting it as an answer for my future reference and for the benefit of others:

Because of the enormous size of data, I had to go with sparse matrix only.

First step is to convert the bag of words to a vectorized format. I have used CountVectorizer (Thanks to @MaxU for this) as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
df2 = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['f2'].str.replace(' ',''))
```

I would like to ignore spaces and use comma as a forced delimiter. I couldn't figure out how to do that so I have replaced the spaces as otherwise vectorizer is splitting the words at spaces.

That has created df1 as a sparse matrix.

Then the other field f1 is converted to a different sparse matrix:

```
df1 = csr_matrix(df[['f1']].fillna(0))
```

Then used hstack to combine both these:
    sparseDF = hstack((df1,df2),format='csr')

Comment: I try your answer with your sample data and it does not work for me. What can be problem? it return `ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried the method, and seems it doesn't work well with single letters. Can you try it with adding one more letter instead (aa, bb, cc instead of a, b, c)? My actual use case had words, and so I didn't realize it wouldn't work with the example I provided.

Comment: Yes, it was one problem. But now I get error `ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions` in `sparseDF = hstack((df1,df2),format='csr')`. Output is matrix with `0` and  `1`?

Comment: @jezrael I have modified the df1 creation step. Instead of calling df['f1'], we should use df[['f1']] so it returns the dataframe instead of just the column. Please let me know if it still throws any error. Thanks for bearing with it. I am just getting started with Python for Data Analysis.